# what does "don't use %APPDATA% " mean when installing notepad++

Tags: git, notepad++

I want to use git and the recommended editor for that was notepad++.

So I downloaded it and then this came up on installation :

[image: the picture]

I don't know whether I should check it or not .

Does it makes any problems while working with git ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option of Notepad++ dates from the early days of Windows, when
`%APPDATA%` did not exist.

`%APPDATA%` stands for `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming` where applications
are supposed to store their private data.
In older versions of Windows, applications stored their data in their installation
folder, but now the Windows guidelines recommend avoiding putting transient data
in the installation folder.

There is no ill-effect from checking this option, but I recommend leaving
it unchecked. Whether checked or unchecked, it has no relationship at all to Git.

Comment: The main downside to using `%AppData%` to store Notepad++ settings is the settings and customizations one makes are no longer system-wide, but user-specific _(unless Notepad++ changed this, as I stopped using it years ago in favor of Atom and VS Code due to the lack of community development and numerous untrusted plugins)_.

Answer (score 4):

This option is useful to install *Notepad++*(along with its config data) on an USB-Stick (like the install option said) for use on several computers. So, if you put your USB-Stick with *Notepad++* into another computer, the options are accessed from the USB-Stick and not from the current computer's `%AppData%` directory.

Repair-Sticks and similar are example use-cases for this scenario.